# pandas dataframe filtering row like groupby

Tags: performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

for example, I have a `dataframe` with these 2 columns `a`, and `b`:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1]
```

I am expecting filtered dataframe: `[5,6,7,2,3,4,9,0,1]`

Without using the `groupby` function (because it is take too long time with a very large `dataframe`, it just not usable), how do I filter with the last 3 items from each group in col. `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's a NumPy based approach -

```
In [89]: a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3])
    ...: b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1])
    ...: 

In [90]: idx = np.append(np.nonzero(a[1:] > a[:-1])[0], a.size-1)[:,None] - [2,1,0]

In [91]: b[idx].ravel()
Out[91]: array([5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 9, 0, 1])
```

If you are receiving those from the columns of a dataframe, `df` named `a` and `b` respectively, as the pre-processing step, we need to extract those as arrays, like so -

```
a = df.a.values
b = df.b.values
```

Please note that this assumes at least three elements per group. For cases with lesser than `3` elems per group read on to the next approach.

---

**Approach #2 :** With [`Scipy's binary dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) to create a mask for selecting elements off `b` -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation as imdilate
def filter_lastN(a, b, N):
    mask = np.zeros(a.size,dtype=bool)
    mask[np.append(np.nonzero(a[1:] > a[:-1])[0],b.size-1)] = 1
    return b[imdilate(mask,np.ones(N),origin=(N-1)//2)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [198]: a
Out[198]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

In [199]: b
Out[199]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1])

In [200]: filter_lastN(a,b,3)
Out[200]: array([5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 9, 0, 1])

In [201]: filter_lastN(a,b,5)
Out[201]: array([5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first for last rows of `groups`, then get previous index values and last select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1]
df =  pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b':b})
print (df)
    a  b
0   1  1
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   1  4
4   1  5
5   1  6
6   1  7
7   2  8
8   2  9
9   2  0
10  2  1
11  2  2
12  2  3
13  2  4
14  3  5
15  3  6
16  3  7
17  3  8
18  3  9
19  3  0
20  3  1
```

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('a',keep='last')
print (df1)
    a  b
6   1  7
13  2  4
20  3  1

idx = sorted(df1.index.tolist() + (df1.index - 1).tolist() + (df1.index - 2).tolist())
print (idx)
[4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20]

print (df.loc[idx])
    a  b
4   1  5
5   1  6
6   1  7
11  2  2
12  2  3
13  2  4
18  3  9
19  3  0
20  3  1
```